# c++, perform function on every array member

Tags: c++, arrays, delegates, function-pointers

i have a question regaring c++ and arrays.

let say i have a class which is called CustomArray, and is nothing more than an generic array wich has attributes for size and capacity, to make the array dynamic. defined as:

```
template<typename T>
class CustomArray
{
public:
    int capacity, size;
    T* items;
    //constructor

    //destructor

    //function1

    //function2

    //etc...
};
```

now i'm kinda stuck, i want to implement a function like:"

```
void performOnAllItems(/*function?*/)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        //perform function on element
    }
}
```

that takes another function as a parameter (if that is possible?) and performs it on all elements. is that possible? and if so... how?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really want "c" in the tags?  The answers for C++ and C are going to be very different.

Comment: C doesn't have templates. The OP is clearly asking for a C++ answer.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::vector` as it already supports `begin(), end()` and *iterators*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add members `begin` and `end` like so:

```
T *begin() { return items; }

T *end() { return items + size; }
```

Create a functor that derives from `std::unary_function`.

E.g.

```
template <typename T>
class MyFunc : std::unary_function<T, void> {
public:
    void operator()(T& t) {
    // ...
    }
};
```

Then call `std::foreach(foo.begin(), foo.end(), MyFunc);`

**Update**

In C++11, you can use a lambda for the foreach:

```
std::foreach(foo.begin(), foo.end(),
              [/* (1) */](T& t) { /* ... */ }
            );
```

If `(1)` isn't empty, then the lambda is a closure; this is known as a capturing lambda, and [Visual C++ 10 Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx) provides a nice example of this.

Comment: I think his question is what the parameter type of the function should be

Comment: Edited to add std::unary_function example

Answer (score 6):

```
template<class functionptr>
void performOnAllItems(functionptr ptr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        ptr(items[i]);
}
```

or

```
typedef void (*functionptr)(T&);
void performOnAllItems(functionptr ptr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        ptr(items[i]);
}
```

The second one greatly limits which functions can be used however, the first does not.

Comment: I'll add that, as written, Mooing's first function should also work with functors (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses))

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You just have to modify `performOnAllItems` to take a function pointer, which returns `void` and takes as a parameter either a `T` or pointer to `T` (per my solution below) that calls that function pointer for each item in the list.

```
template <typename T>
void CustomArray::performOnAllItems(void (*action)(T*))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        action(items + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, you caught a different error in my code. Let me edit it for you.